# I want to show current search value after search function works

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am creating this for my varsity project. I am not so expert about it. so, I need someone to help me or guide me how to do it. Please see the image below:
[image: search page image at current situation on my web page]

When i search with some value putting in input field it goes empty after search. 
But i want to show current search value after search results show as like as the image below: 
[image: expected result on my webpage]

The id's of the search fields are: application_number, document_number
Can anyone suggest any URL where can i find this solution or write me code for me. I used php and mysql for show the search result. Here is the code if this helps you to understand:

```
 if(isset($_POST['searchbtn'])):

        $application_number = trim($_POST['application_number']);
        $document_number = trim($_POST['document_number']);


       $sql_search = "SELECT * FROM search_info LEFT JOIN country ON country.`country_id`=`search_info`.`country_id` WHERE search_info.`application_number` = '$application_number' AND search_info.`document_number` = '$document_number' AND search_info.`is_deleted`=0";

        $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql_search);
        $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);
        if($count>0):

       $search_result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);


 ?>

  <tr>
                <td><center><?=$search_result['bill_number']?></center></td>
                  <td><center><?=$search_result['application_number']?></center></td>
                  <td><center><?=$search_result['application_date']?></center></td>
                  <td><center><?=$search_result['document_number']?></center></td>
                  <td><center><?=$search_result['name']?></center></td>
                  <td ><center><?=$search_result['Country_Name']?></center></td>
                  <td><center><?=$search_result['type_pass']?></center></td>
                  <td><center><?=$search_result['time_frame']?></center></td>
                  <td><center><?=$search_result['acquisition_place']?></center></td>
                  <td style="color:<?=$search_result['color']?>"><center><?=$search_result['application_status']?></center></td>

        </tr>
        <?php else:?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="10">No Record Found</td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif;?>
```

I think it can be done with jquery or ajax. But i don't know how to do it. My coding skill is beginner level, so please consider it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if your project requires security enhancements, but if this should get the job done. It checks that the posted variable exists, if not it sets the variable to empty then it simply echoes that in the input.

```
<?php
     $document_number = (isset($_POST["document_number"])) ? $_POST["document_number"] : "";
     $application_number = (isset($_POST["application_number"])) ? $_POST["application_number"] : "";
?>
<input type="text" name="application_number" value="<?=$application_number?>">
<input type="text" name="document_number" value="<?=$document_number?>">
```

Comment: I don't have to worry about any security issue. I know my code is low security.. I should put a value in input field for search. and here <input type="text" name="application_number" value="<?=$application_number?>">  i already set the value. can you please clear it to me. Should i replace this code to my current code, or put before or after my current code?

Comment: @JahidulIslamTusher I would use the isset code from my example and just use the value="<?=$application_number?>" in your code. You didn't include the HTML of your code so I had to make due with what was provided.

Comment: ` <form action="post">
        Application NO: <input type="text" name="application_number" value="">
        Document No: <input type="text" name="application_number" value="">
        <input type="submit" name="searchbtn" value="submit">
      </form>`